# How to prevent parent activity of a dialog to show when opening new activity?

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

Simply my problem is that i have the following scenario:

I have activity A ... and there is a custom dialog appearing on it .. it's quite big but it's not an activity it's just a dialog ..

Clicking on a certain item on that dialog opens new activity B

After clicking on the dialog .. I need to dismiss the dialog and open Activity B
what happens is that Activity A appears for like a second or less then Activity B opens ..

I've tried dismissing the dialog after calling startActivity() .. but still the A activity still shows briefly before opening activity B ..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what should happen if you press back button from Activity B? Should activity A be shown without/with the dialog on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative to @user543 solution (which also valid) you can hold on with dismissal of the dialog. Launch new activity from dialog and leave dialog alone (or better maintain a flag for later dialog dismiss), activity will appear immediately on top of Activity A and it's dialog. When user will click back button, onStart and onResume of Activity A will be called, so check if that flag and dismiss the dialog there

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the dialog in onStop(). Because after loading Activity B only onStop() will call in Activity A.

Define some boolean variable like:

```
boolean isClicked=false;
```

Whenever u r performing some click functionaly in dialog, then make this variable as 'true'. Then in onStop() check like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
            if(isClicked)
              {  
                 //dismiss dialog
              }
}
```

Comment: well, what will happen if user open the Dialog and phone's screen goes off due timeout? I suppose onStop() of Activity A will also be called, which will in turn dismiss the dialog, and so next time the app will be restored there will be no dialog. Is that acceptable for the app?

Comment: Thanks alot i've tried the other answer and both will work just fine